# Refreshing jQuery Mobile elements after 'manual' manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

OK, so here's what I'm trying to do :

- I have an ultra-basic jQuery Mobile page
- I'm tweaking one-or-two things via JavaScript (the Chrome console), like
  setting `$("#the-header").attr("data-position","fixed");`

However (and that was pretty much expected), the changes won't show up.

How am I supposed to make the page refresh? (wait I don't want the original page, but the final one *with* the tweaks, rebuilt).

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE:**

Hmmm... after countless (blind) experiments I think I'm rather close to a solution :

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.trigger("create");
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing changing or appending toolbars (header/footer) dynamically to active page, you have to call two functions.

- To enhance toolbar when dynamically added:

  ```
  $.mobile.activePage.trigger("pagecreate");
  ```
- To modify options of existing toolbar

  ```
  $(".selector").fixedtoolbar();
  ```

To reset page's height and remove extra padding after adding toolbar dynamically or modify options.

```
$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight(); /* works only on 1.3.2 and later */
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/KJnUe/)**

---

**Update:**

Alternatively, you can fix toolbars using `$(".selector").fixedtoolbar();` instead of `$(".selector").attr("data-position", "fixed");`. In this case, you don't need to call `.trigger("pagecreate")`, unless you append them dynamically into active page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#the-header").css({ 'data-position': 'fixed' });
```

OR

```
$("#the-header").attr('style','data-position:fixed');
```